# Getting an issue while importing data from MongoDB and Apache Solr using mongo-connector

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, solr, pymongo

We are trying to integrate MongoDB and Apache Solr. I have followed the steps as mentioned in the
website:-
https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/02/03/indexing-mongodb-data-in-apache-solr

I am currently using Apache Solr version 6.4.2 , Mongo DB Version 4.2, Python Version 3.8.3.

I have followed below steps:-

Installed the mongo-connector using the command `pip install mongo-connector`.

-Created the Mongo DB path in C:/mongo/data where all access is present.

- Now i am trying to initiate the mongo connector to push the document from MongoDB to Apache Solr by hitting the command

`mongo-connector --unique-key=id -n solr.wlslog -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/solrmongo -d solr_doc_manager`

and I am getting below error as

```
2020-11-30 17:45:30,678 [INFO] mongo_connector.connector:402 - MongoConnector: Starting connection thread MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, replicaset='rs0')
2020-11-30 17:45:30,678 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:214 - OplogThread: Run thread started
2020-11-30 17:45:30,679 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:216 - OplogThread: Getting cursor
2020-11-30 17:45:30,679 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:881 - OplogThread: reading last checkpoint as None 
2020-11-30 17:45:30,680 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:750 - OplogThread: Newest oplog entry has timestamp Timestamp(1606737929, 2).
2020-11-30 17:45:30,682 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:570 - OplogThread: Dumping set of collections ['solr.wlslog'] 
2020-11-30 17:45:30,682 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:665 - OplogThread: Using bulk upsert function for collection dump
2020-11-30 17:45:30,684 [INFO] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:646 - Bulk upserting approximately 1 docs from collection 'solr.wlslog'
2020-11-30 17:45:30,686 [CRITICAL] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:713 - Exception during collection dump
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\solr_doc_manager.py", line 292, in <genexpr>
    batch = list(next(cleaned) for i in range(self.chunk_size))
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\oplog_manager.py", line 668, in do_dump
    upsert_all(dm)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\oplog_manager.py", line 651, in upsert_all
    dm.bulk_upsert(docs_to_dump(from_coll), mapped_ns, long_ts)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\util.py", line 33, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector\doc_managers\solr_doc_manager.py", line 292, in bulk_upsert
    batch = list(next(cleaned) for i in range(self.chunk_size))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
2020-11-30 17:45:30,690 [ERROR] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:723 - OplogThread: Failed during dump collection cannot recover! Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, replicaset='rs0'), 'local'), 'oplog.rs')
2020-11-30 17:45:30,690 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:856 - OplogThread: no checkpoint to update.
2020-11-30 17:45:30,690 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:227 - OplogThread: Last entry is the one we already processed.  Up to date.  Sleeping.
2020-11-30 17:45:31,679 [ERROR] mongo_connector.connector:408 - MongoConnector: OplogThread <OplogThread(Thread-2, started 16724)> unexpectedly stopped! Shutting down
2020-11-30 17:45:31,679 [INFO] mongo_connector.connector:478 - MongoConnector: Stopping all OplogThreads
2020-11-30 17:45:31,679 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:371 - OplogThread: exiting due to join call.
```

***Troubleshooting Steps:***

I have checked mongo and solr connections.Both are up and running

The DB data folder has all the necessary permissions.

Will be grateful if you could guide me further.

Comment: Not sure about mongo connector...But I would suggest to use the monstache tool

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AbhijitBashetti. Can you please suggest any reference example link where i could get this integration between Apache Solr and MongoDB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661890/mongodb-4-x-real-time-sync-to-elasticsearch-6-x/56663568#56663568............In this example data is pushed to elasticsearch...but you can also push it to solr as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AbhijitBashetti. But my architecture team is suggesting to use mongo-connector with this one. So i can take it as an learning later but right now  I am looking the one with mongo-connector one.